# Database modeller for JPA with visual diagrams

Tags: java, jpa, database-design

I am looking for a tool to help in designing and implementing database and entities for a Java project. Probably we are using JPA or direct Hibernate. The features I look for are:

- Design database with visual modeller
- Create entities from the visual model
- Update entity changes to the visual model
- Import existing database schema as visual model / entity classes

So the idea is to originally create a database model with visual tool, then auto-to generate entities from it and afterwards modify the code and expect the visual diagram to reflect the changes (so it works for documentation purposes). I want a full representation of table schema, not just an ER diagram.

There have been other questions (of course) but they don't seem to be so specific to Java/JPA and don't have as strict requirements. They are also often just about generating a diagram from code or database schema - they don't require bi-directional support (if that's the right term).

The products I found so far are:

- [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/) (6.7.1): supports generating Java classes from UML, JPA needs specific templates (sounds too tricky). Doesn't identify new elements from classes.
- [DbSchema](http://www.dbschema.com/): Seems to offer some visualization of schemas, couldn't get it started so can't say much. Commercial, but it also has a free version.
- [Omondo EclipseUML](http://www.ejb3.org/products_architecturee.html): seems to have <strike>[some sort of support](http://www.forum-omondo.com/documentation_eclipseuml_2008/Eclipse_Database/Create_New_JPA_Classes/index.html)</strike>, but [costs like hell](http://www.ejb3.org/pricing.html).
- [SchemaSpy](http://schemaspy.sourceforge.net/): Supports only creating documentation from an existing database schema. Also couldn't find a comprehensive graph.
- [Toad Data Modeller](http://modeling.inside.quest.com/index.jspa): Somewhat messy homepage, however *seems* to support creating diagrams from existing DB as well as creating DB schema from a diagram. Doesn't have code generation facilities.
- [Eclipse WTP](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/)'s [Dali JPA Tools](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/dali/): No support for visual presentation, however targeted at providing aid to JPA development.

As a conclusion, Dali seems most interesting, because it's targeted for JPA development. However, it doesn't seem to have a visual diagram of any sort (just outlines and stuff).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at th **JPA Diagram Editor** for Eclipse, the first Milestone has been released recently. From [the announcement](http://dev.eclipse.org/blogs/raev/2010/08/18/jpa-diagram-editor-first-milestone-released/):

> I am happy to announce that the JPA
>   Diagram Editor project made its first
>   milestone release - 0.5 RC1. Just
>   follow the [installation
>   instructions](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JPA_Diagram_Editor_Project#How_to_Install), posted on the
>   [project’s wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JPA_Diagram_Editor_Project), and you are ready
>   to build your JPA model in a diagram.
>   There is a nice Getting Started
>   tutorial to help your first steps. If
>   you want to take a quick look before
>   installing, then check our [demo](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xZf6pOHX178)
>   on YouTube.
>
> [image: An example of a diagram created by the JPA editor]
>
> The JPA Diagram Editor is a new
>   incubating project in the WTP
>   Incubator. The project is initiated by
>   SAP and aims to contribute the
>   existing JPA Diagram Editor from the
>   SAP NetWeaver Developer Studio, and
>   continue its future development in the
>   Eclipse community. This contribution
>   is based on the Graphiti project - the
>   new graphics modeling infrastructure
>   in Eclipse.
>
> The official 0.5 version of the
>   project will provide a stable release
>   of the initial contribution. Due to
>   the migration to Graphiti, there are
>   some bugs to be cleaned and we are
>   actively working on them.
>   Nevertheless, we decided to release
>   early to hear your feedback sooner. If
>   you eventually find a bug, then please
>   report it in the WTP Incubator
>   Bugzilla (use component
>   wtp.inc.jpaeditor). You can check the
>   list of already reported bugs if that
>   bug has already been found - we are
>   actively testing at the moment.
>
> Please, note that currently the JPA
>   Diagram Editor supports only JPA 1.0
>   projects. This mean that you will not
>   see the “Open Diagram” action in the
>   context menu of JPA 2.0 projects. JPA
>   2.0 support is definitely on our radar screen. We will start working on it
>   after releasing the stable 0.5
>   version.

Comment: This looks really promising (installing atm), just what I was looking for. Too bad it's not "complete" yet and is probably shaky and buggy. I really like the integration with Dali JPA tools. This should be perfect... however, as it isn't too mature quite yet, I will gladly hear from other choices as well :)

Comment: @Tuukka Yes, it's very new and might not be that mature. But I wanted at least to mention it (since it's new).

Comment: For anyone interested, I tried out the product. It is still in a rather basic level, however supports the basic CRUD operations on entities and their properties. It also looks specific enough (to JPA/Java) to actually aid in the development/documentation. Also, other data modeling products often reflect the database itself, however, this product lives at the code level and actually reflects the entities. After all, what do you do with a database table/column that is not used in the code... I'm not deeply into Dali JPA tools, but probably database can be reflected with this as well.

Comment: @Pascal Thivent, Could you provide the way for my question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12979282/cannot-add-embeddable-classes-in-jpa-diagram-editor

Comment: https://wiki.eclipse.org/JPA_Diagram_Editor_Project hasn't been updated for 3 years

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [JPA Modeler - Netbeans](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/53057/jpa-modeler) tool, will be fit for your requirement :

> designing and implementing database and entities for a Java project

You can find the demo here : [JPA Modeler Demo - Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g8B764qNkc0) .
It is released recently and in initial phase.