# Cannot add Embeddable classes in JPA Diagram Editor?

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa, eclipse-plugin

I use `Eclipse IDE Plugin` `Dali Java Persistence Tools - JPA Diagram Editor` for `JPA OR Mapping` diagram.

I cannot see and add my `Embeddable` classes in diagram.

1. What I need to do configuration for that in `Eclipse`?
2. Is there other plugin for `JPA OR Mapping` diagram?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently in the Dali tools you can use the JPA Details and JPA Structure views to edit your Embeddable classes and attributes. You will also get code assist and validation in the Java editor. JPA Diagram editor support for creating/editing Embeddables is being added for Kepler. That work has been completed for Kepler M3, you can provide feedback on this bug if you have any suggestions.

- [Bug 364602 - JPA Diagram Editor Embeddable Support](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=364602)
- [Design Docs](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Embeddables_and_Mapped_Superclasses_in_JPA_Diagram_Editor)